# Basic question on second covariant derivative

Tags: riemannian-geometry

I am having a question on the wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_covariant_derivative

Using the notation therein I don't get why
$(\nabla_{u}\nabla_{v}w )^a=u^c\nabla_{c}v^b\nabla_{b}w^a$.

It is clear that $(\nabla_{u}\nabla_{v}w )^a=(u^c\nabla_{c}v^b\nabla_{b}w)^a$.

What do I miss?

Comment: The right-hand side of the former equation means the same as the right-hand side of the latter, otherwise you'd be coordinate-dependent. That's the thing I don't like with the index notation for the covariant derivative. It suggests that a coordinate is derived, but actually the coordinate is extracted from the result.